# Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/login'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/login'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django-views, django-urls, django-login

urls.py/telusko

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls'))  
]
```

urls.py/accounts

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


# create a path or url for REGISTER

urlpatterns = [
    
    path("registration",views.registration,name="registration"),
    path("login",views.login,name="login")
]
```

views.py/accounts

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        
        User = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        
        if User is not None:
            auth.login(request, User)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid details')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return redirect(request,'login')    
    
    

def registration(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        
        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request,'username already exists')
                return redirect('registration')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request,'email taken')
                return redirect('registration')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email, first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
                user.save();
                messages.info(request,'user created')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'password not matching...')
            return redirect('registration')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
     return render(request,'registration.html')
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                     <div class="float-right">
                        <ul class="top_links">
                           <li><a href="accounts/registration">REGISTER</a></li>
                           <li><a href="accounts/login">LOGIN</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

login.html/template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" placeholder="login">
    </form>

    <div>
        {% for Message in messages %}
        <h3> {{Message}} </h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

above is code for register and login pages
the problem is just  simple i.e: i'm able to register in registration page similarly i'm not able get the login page when i click on login page i'm encountering this kinda issue help me out with this error

the error occuring :
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login
Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/login'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/login'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/login'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/login'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\vinod\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  accounts.views.login
Python Executable:  C:\Users\vinod\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.2
Python Path:
['C:\Users\vinod\telusko\projects',
'C:\Users\vinod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip',
'C:\Users\vinod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs',
'C:\Users\vinod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib',
'C:\Users\vinod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310',
'C:\Users\vinod\Envs\test',
'C:\Users\vinod\Envs\test\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 15 Dec 2022 15:47:04 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use reverse() method  instead of redirect('pathname') and use django templating tag (DTL)

links

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urlresolvers/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/